# Choice of DSL framework

Tags: .net, dsl

I am working on a project that requires me to define a DSL. Since coming up with the right DSL is critical for my project, I decided to evaluate existing frameworks that help in defining DSLs,parsing it and code generation(which has to be in a .NET based language) The frameworks I considered are :

1. Boo language that has a customizable compiler and pythonish syntax ideal for defining a DSL.
2. Windows powershell that supports extensible commandlets.
3. Microsoft DSL tools that support visual modeling,but less flexible(in my opinion)
4. ANTLR which is proven tool
5. C# fluent interfaces.(Not so happy with this)
6. Oslo framework (Is it mature to be used in production?)

There are pros and cons of each of the framework mentioned above and I am unable to make a decision.Given a choice between the above frameworks, which one would you choose and why?

Is there any other framework so fundamental that I might have missed out?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 - great question, and one that I'm grappling with as well. I looked at the Early Access version of the book Building Domain Specific Languages in Boo and found it frustrating - the tools did not seem mature. I also believe that PowerShell shows great promise in this area. And I picked up the book on ANTLR, too. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776265/c-how-to-parse-arbitrary-strings-into-expression-trees) that touched the subject of DSL's, it was suggested to me to use a combination of [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) and [DLR](http://dlr.codeplex.com/). I don't know stable they are however. Irony is an Alpha, and DLR, although stable, is still in v0.9. I'm aiming to start using Irony myself in a week or two, so then I will be able to provide some feedback. On the bright side however - they are both opensource, so you can fix bugs yourself.

Comment: That's sad news. :( However it has been working very well for me for over 1.5 years now (including in production), and I don't even have the latest version. So I think it's still a good option, until something better comes along.

Answer (score 3):

Xtext: http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to implement an external DSLs , Spoofax ( http://strategoxt.org/Spoofax )is a nice Language Workbench to do this. It is a parser-based textual Langauge Workbench that leverage several state-of-art technology such as SDF , Stratego. Besides the DSL implemenation , you could get a very rich editor services such as, code completion , outline view , intellisense etc.

It comes with a nice sample DSL implementation and code generation to Java. It might also work as a starting point to get started with the tools.

Following tutorial details about the usage this langauge workbench : http://strategoxt.org/Spoofax/Tour .

Hope it helps!

Edit -1 :

Following is an example of a language implemented using this Langauge Workbench : http://mobl-lang.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Jetbrains have a visual tool to aid in language development, forgotten the name but their front page has it on it.  I believe its free and partially open sourced.

Answer (score 0):

The [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is an integrated set of tools for defining arbitrary langauges, including DSLs, automating the construction of parsers, analyzers, and code generators for the defined languages.