# String Linq to IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

How can I do this :

```
string queryString = @"from c in Stuffs select c";
IQueryable<Stuffs> q = StringToIQueryable(queryString);
```

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776265/c-how-to-parse-arbitrary-strings-into-expression-trees

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but be careful. It looks susceptible to sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

See [dynamic linq library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) from Scott Gu that describes how to compose predicates of a linq query from strings. I'm not sure if it's possible to pass a whole linq query but with some custom parsing you should achieve what you want!